# Closure problems in class definition

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, closures

I'm using CoffeScript to create an angular application.

I have a strange problem with this code.

**webService.coffe (simplificated)**

```
ServiceManager.service "webService", class
    constructor : (@$http) ->

    # Private

    handleResult = (callback, errorCallback, authErrorCallback) =>
        (result) =>
            if result.result then callback result
            else
                if result.code is 102 then @logout authErrorCallback, errorCallback
                else errorCallback result.code, result.error

    get : (url, callback, errorCallback) ->
        @$http.get url
        .success handleResult callback, errorCallback, (=> @get url, callback, errorCallback)
        .error handleError errorCallback

    logout : (callback, errorCallback) ->
        @$http.get "logout"
        .success callback()
        .error errorCallback()
```

In this simplificated code, I get the error `_Class.logout is not a function` when `handleResult` is called and the error code is 102.

The `=>` operator should resolve this problem but it's not. I don't understand why...

---

**Javascript compiled code of webService.coffee**

```
ServiceManager.service("webService", (function() {
  var handleResult;

  function _Class($http) {
    this.$http = $http;
  }

  handleResult = function(callback, errorCallback, authErrorCallback) {
    return function(result) {
      if (result.result) {
        return callback(result);
      } else {
        if (result.code === 102) {
          return _Class.logout(authErrorCallback, errorCallback);
        } else {
          return errorCallback(result.code, result.error);
        }
      }
    };
  };

  _Class.prototype.get = function(url, callback, errorCallback) {
    return this.$http.get(url).success(handleResult(callback, errorCallback, ((function(_this) {
      return function() {
        return _this.get(url, callback, errorCallback);
      };
    })(this)))).error(handleError(errorCallback));
  };

  _Class.prototype.logout = function(callback, errorCallback) {
    return this.$http.get("logout").success(callback()).error(errorCallback());
  };

  return _Class;

})());
```

Comment: What happened to the `ServiceManager.service "webService"` part in the compiled version?

Comment: Oops my bad, paste mistake :-) I have edited

Comment: The solution I have found from know is to declare `handleResult` outside of the constructor and the define it in the constructor. This way, it is accessible form all the class and `this` point to the current instance of the object. But It's a litle durty...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you're defining `handleResult` as a static, private variable inside your class IIFE. It cannot access the `@logout` instance method therefore, CS does compile it to a static `_Class.logout` invocation  which cannot work.

There are a few ways around this:

- make `handleResult` a private instance variable, and move everything inside the constructor - the declarations of `@get` and `@logout` as well.
- give `handleResult` an instance parameter to which you pass `@`, so that it can invoke the instance method on it
- only call the `authErrorCallback` and do the `@logout` and things inside there.

Given that your service class will only be instantiated once as a singleton anyway, the first is probably the most sensible.

However, you really should consider not doing so much complicated callback stuff anyway. Just use promises:

```
ServiceManager.service "webService", class
    constructor : (@$http) ->

    get: (url) ->
        @$http.get url
        .then (result) =>
            if result.result then result
            else if result.code is 102 then @logout().then(=> @get url)
            else throw result.error

    logout: () ->
        @$http.get "logout"
```

Comment: Yes, the first solution is the one I have also found.
The code I have given is simplificated :-) It's much more complexe in the real context and handle result is use to handle response all calls of my webservice. It's why I have done it his way.